# ssh with command loses tab-completion

Tags: ssh

I have a handy alias as follows:

```
sshpass -p "the_password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.0.123
```

That will give me a quick way to login to a remote device, and get a command prompt which has tab completion.

But the first thing I then ALWAYS do, is `cd` to a different directory. Consequently I want to add that as a command to the end of the line, like this:

```
sshpass -p "the_password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.0.123 'cd /tmp/Data/fx'
```

But if I do that then I don't get a prompt at all! It just sits there doing nothing. Next, I tried to make it give me a command prompt, by using this:

```
sshpass -p "the_password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.0.123 'cd /tmp/Data/fx; /bin/bash -i'
```

That nearly works.

I have changed to the right directory, and I have a command prompt. But, I don't have any tab-completion, and the up-arrow doesn't show me the most recent commands.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try with `-t` to force a pty allocation? `ssh` with a command is not really meant for interactive use though...

Comment: Cool, yes, the -t option works.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `/bin/bash -i` you are launching another instance of the shell.  Therefore it's normal that you don't have access to your previous history.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't explain why the tab-completion doesn't work.